# Shading issues on beveled area

Tags: bevel, smooth

I have an auto smoothed object on which i manually added a bevel. A resulting curve is brighter than the rest and I don't know why.
[image]

Also when I increase angle of auto smooth so it affects all edges I want, a shading issue becomes even worse.
[image]

[image]

How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with your images. Image 1: standard shading in Blender. Image 2: standard behavior of Auto-smooth.